# Take image sizes and generate gallery from folder

Tags: php, html, photoswipe

I want to create Gallery using Photoswipe plugin but I want to show thumbs and images automatically form folder.
Photoswipe requires the size of the image, so I want the script to take the size of each image.

Pictures in folder are numbered from 0-14 and it showing images but I don't know how to take size of each image from gallery/ and put it to: data-size="'.$imageSize.'":

```
<?php
  $dir="gallery/";
  $thumbsDir="gallery/thumbs/";
  for($i=0; $i<=14; $i++)
  {
    echo 
      '<figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <a href="'.$dir.$i.'.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="'.$imageSize.'" data-index="'.$i.'">
          <img src="'.$thumbsDir.$i.'.jpg" width="412px" itemprop="thumbnail" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
        </a>
      </figure>';
  }
?>
```

This should look like this: data-size="1920x1080".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make use of [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), for example.

```
<?php
  $dir="gallery/";
  $thumbsDir="gallery/thumbs/";
  for($i=0; $i<=14; $i++)
  {
    if (!file_exists($dir.$i.'.jpg')) continue;
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($dir.$i.'.jpg');

    echo 
      '<figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <a href="'.$dir.$i.'.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="'.$width.'x'.$height.'" data-index="'.$i.'">
          <img src="'.$thumbsDir.$i.'.jpg" width="412px" itemprop="thumbnail" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
        </a>
      </figure>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: After added this : `if (!file_exists($dir.$i.'.jpg')) continue;
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($dir.$i.'.jpg');`
Images are not showing, so i removed:  `if (!file_exists($dir.$i.'.jpg')) continue;`
And i have error: `Warning: getimagesize(gallery/0.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\gallery.php on line 13`
Images are showing so directory is valid but if it want to get image size, it can't open this.

Comment: @Rafaucau That's why I added it, so as to check the image exists before trying to display it. Check your path is correct.

Comment: To use that path like that, images must be in `C:\wamp64\www\gallery\*.jpg` and you should have a folder called thumbs in there also. If not then fix the paths.

Comment: Adding trailing slash in .htaccess caused the problem.
HTML has seen another path than PHP. That's why the images were displayed, but there was error with taking size.

So I set different paths to get the image size and to display it. Now it works.

Thank You very much for your help.